# C# Precompile affects line numbers?

Tags: c#, debugging, precompiled

I'm trying to debug a problem in prod from a reported stack trace, but the line numbers aren't lining up? Do precompiles affect line numbers, and does the code in the "else" (as it were) count toward line numbers?

For example:

```
1    #if DEBUG
2    DoItemA();
3    #else
4    DoItemB()
5    #endif
```

So is that 2 lines of code (when compiled), 5 lines of code, or 1 line of code (the only line calculated to pertinent at pre-compile)

When that runs, and my stack trace says the error was on line 3, how did it count line numbers?

Comment: Just ask your editor for line #3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no separate precompiler in C#. So the line numbers in the stack-trace should be identical to the line numbers in the original file.